# A destructuring assignment pattern doesn't seem clear in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, destructuring

From the website [exploringjs](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html)

> Before ES6, there was no corresponding mechanism for extracting data.
>   That’s what destructuring is – it lets you extract multiple properties
>   from an object via an object pattern. For example, on the left-hand
>   side of an assignment:

```
const { first: f, last: l } = obj;
```

And I understand the sample below, for example, one would be assigning the `createServer` method from the `http` module to a variable of the same name.

```
const { createServer } = require('http');
```

But what about this:

```
const { parse: parseUrl } = require('url');
```

How do you use this in your code?

Comment: *"How do you use this in your code?"* unclear what you are asking. It assigns it to a variable with a different name. `console.log(parse)` So if you have want a better fitting name you can alter it instead of having to use what the export is.

Comment: it's the "same" as `var parse = require('url').parseUrl ;`, just less clear semantically...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use this when you want to change the name of the variable coming from `require('url')`

because require('url') contain `parse` but lets say you already have variable called `parse` in your current scope and you want to have `parse` from `require('url')`  in this case you use this pattern to rename it to `parseUrl`

Example:

```
const parse = "some value";
const { parse: parseUrl }  = require('url');
console.log(parse); // "some value";
console.log(parseUrl); // value coming from require('url');
```

Comment: Ahh, so this pattern allows you to assign the `parse` property to a variable name of your choosing in this case `parseUrl`, for an instance like you've created where `parse` was already being used...

Comment: Yes exactly this is the common use case for it

Answer (score 1):

It is simply extracting the `parse` data and creating a `parseUrl` variable in this scope.

This can be really handy when (let's suppose) you work with APIs and want to use variables instead of member access :

```
const {id: serviceID} = await fetchDefaultService();
const {id: uid} = await fetchUser(serviceID, uid);
```

It simply allows to have control over naming (`parseUrl` has more meaning than `parse`) and allows you to avoid potential conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

The line in your example peels off the `parse` function from the `url` module, and renames it `parseUrl`.  You can use it like this:

```
> const { parse: parseUrl } = require('url')
undefined
> parseUrl('http://stackoverflow.com/')
Url {
  protocol: 'http:',
  slashes: true,
  auth: null,
  host: 'stackoverflow.com',
  port: null,
  hostname: 'stackoverflow.com',
  hash: null,
  search: null,
  query: null,
  pathname: '/',
  path: '/',
  href: 'http://stackoverflow.com/' }
```

That's just copy/pasted from a `node` repl.  Open your terminal, and type the command `node`, and you can interactively type js and test what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Destructuring is a great feature that helps you extract object properties or elements from array super easily 
let's understand it by examples

- in the first example because obj has a prop called name we can extract it from it
- so if the object has a prop we can extract it.

  ```js
  let obj = {
    name :'maged' 
  }
  let {name} = obj ;  // have this prop 
  let {fullName} = obj ; // don't have this prop 
  console.log(name) ; // maged  
  console.log(fullName) ;  // undefined
  ```

  - in this example we return an object from a function which similer to the **require** function in **nodejs** which return the export object

```js
function require(module) {
  return {
      name : module ,
      method1: '1' ,
      method2 : '2'
   }
}
let obj =  require('url') ; 
let {name,method1,method2} = obj ; 
console.log(name) ; // url 
console.log(method1) ; // 1 
console.log(method2) ;  // 2
```

- as you can see we extract multi properties from the returned object so easily
- in our third example we will see how we can extract prop to a new  variable name
  +

```js
let obj = {
  a :'a' ,
  b:'b' 
}
let {a:first , b:second} = obj ;
console.log(first) ; // a 
console.log(second) // b
console.log(a); // Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

as you can see we extract the properties as new variable names which is great ,

- now to the last example we will see how to assign default value to the variable if its not exist in the object which is good for things like default object properties when passed to a function ,

```js
let obj = {
  fullName : 'Sniper' 
}
let {fullName='super'} = obj ; // sniper from the obj 
console.log(fullName) ; 
let {name='maged'} = obj ; // maged because undefined in the obj 
console.log(name) ;
```

I hope this examples somehow help you to understand Destructuring and how its work

> Note Destructuring works with arrays